# Override the "default servlet" behaviour for URL pattern "/" in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a particular JSP which I would like to serve at the root page of my website (the URL "/"). All other requests should be served statically. So naturally I configured my `web.xml` like so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately it seems that `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` does not do what I need it to do. Instead of only handling the "/" URL, [it is special-cased, and functions as the "default mapping"](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html#433), handling **all requests not captured by other URL patterns**.

In this particular case, the `default` servlet's `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` handles *all* URLs. A request to "/" comes up as a 404, and the `index` servlet never gets invoked no matter what request is made.

Is there a way to explicitly map the "/" URL, and only that URL, to a particular servlet?

Comment: No, that yields a web site which returns a 404 error no matter what I request.

Comment: Nope. Cleared the whole `web.xml`. Anyway it's solved, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an empty pattern string to match the context root:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a horrible time locating hard documentation about this.